# Python Tabs Uneven in Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-writing, csv

I am having troubles with writing a tab delimited text file in Python. I have it set to write the item ID, width, depth, etc., but when I look at the data file at the end, even though 2 product ID's are the same length, one will be tabbed correctly, and the other will not. This is what it look like in the text file:

```
Product ID      Tariff Number   Net Depth   Net Height  Net Length  Net width   Net Weight

7TAD012610R0010 3917320010  .61 m       .203 m              .61 m               
7TAD012610R0012 3917320010  .66 m       .229 m              .66 m               
7TAD012610R0013 3917320010  .711 m      .178 m              .711 m              
7TAD012610R0014     3917320010  .711 m      .178 m              .711 m              
7TAD013190R0000     7307193060  .102 m      .152 m              .114 m              
7TAD013180R0000     7307193060  .102 m      .203 m              .127 m              
7TAD013180R0002     7307193060  .114 m      .076 m              .127 m              
7TAD013190R0002     7307193060  .102 m      .152 m              .114 m              
7TAD013190R0004     7307193060  .102 m      .152 m              .127 m              
7TAD013180R0005     7307193060  .262 m      .188 m              .107 m
```

As you can see, the first 3 are not tabbed out as much as the others even though they appear to be the same length, and have the same number of characters... Here is part of the code I have written for this:

```
for URL in URLList:
    try:
        dataSoup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read())
        print("Page", pageNo, "retrieved")



        #Try to find data of that type
        try:
            proID = columnLookup(URL, "Product ID:")
            fh.write(str(proID))
            fh.write("\t")
            if len(PID[pageNo - 1]) < 8:
                fh.write("\t")
        except:
            fh.write("\t\t")
        try:
            fh.write(dataSoup.find(id="CustomsTariffNumber").next_sibling.next_sibling.div.text)
            fh.write("\t")
        except:
            fh.write("\t\t")
        try:
            fh.write(dataSoup.find(id="ProductNetDepth").next_sibling.next_sibling.div.text)
            fh.write("\t")
            if len(dataSoup.find(id="ProductNetDepth").next_sibling.next_sibling.div.text) < 8:
                fh.write("\t")
            print("Net Depth:", dataSoup.find(id="ProductNetDepth").next_sibling.next_sibling.div.text)

        #If none is found, skip over that column: Leave it blank
        except:
            fh.write("\t\t")
```

If anyone could let me know why it's doing this and how to fix it, that would be great. I think it has something to do with the characters it contains, but I am at a loss for ideas to fix it, I've tried adding and removing tabs, trying to find the length of both, and it seems like nothing works.

If it is the right problem, would this be the proper way to strip it?:

```
        try:
            proID = columnLookup(URL, "Product ID:")
            fh.write(str(proID).strip())
            fh.write("\t")
            if len(PID[pageNo - 1]) < 8:
                fh.write("\t")
        except:
            fh.write("\t\t")
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't whitespace at the end of the product ID?

Comment: I don't believe so, should I try to strip it first?

Comment: That would be my first port of call.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that now... I'll let you know if it works or not!

Comment: Hmmm... It didn't work... I did it correctly, right?:

Comment: try:
                proID = columnLookup(URL, "Product ID:")
                fh.write(str(proID).strip())
                fh.write("\t")
                if len(PID[pageNo - 1]) < 8:
                    fh.write("\t")
            except:
                fh.write("\t\t")

This is what I did... I just added .strip() to the end of the file writer

Comment: Sorry, that got messed up... I'll add the code to the question

Comment: is there a reason you do not use the built-in [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module? you can configure it to use tabs instead of commas.

Comment: I was told by my boss to use a tab delimited, but I can ask him if I can go ahead and use that, I thought it might be easier!

Comment: How would I go about making it tab delimited instead of comma?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I found it, would I do delimiter="\t" in csv.writer?

Comment: exactly. that's what i meant.

Comment: Thank you very much... It is working much better in a csv!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better way to do this... I have decided to just go with the built-in csv file reader/writer as suggested by hiro protagonist. This is how I did it if anyone would like to know:

```
        with open('data.csv', 'a') as dataFile:
            csvWriter = csv.writer(dataFile, delimiter=',')
            csvWriter.writerow(productData)
```

I then have the data values stored in productData!

Thanks for the help everyone!